# Issues with deserializing Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have some json like this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "result": {
        "@type": "address_result__201301",
        "barcode": "1301013030001010212212333002003031013",
        "bsp": "044",
        "dpid": "99033785",
        "postcode": "4895",
        "state": "QLD",
        "suburb": "COOKTOWN",
        "city": null,
        "country": "AUSTRALIA"
    },
    "search_date": "03-12-2014 15:31:03",
    "search_parameters": {},
    "time_taken": 636,
    "transaction_id": "f8df8791-531e-4043-9093-9f35881f6bb9",
    "root_transaction_id": "a1fa1426-b973-46ec-b61b-0fe5518033de"
}
```

Then I created some classes:

```
public class Address
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Result results { get; set; }
    public string search_date { get; set; }
    public SearchParameters search_parameters { get; set; }
    public int time_taken { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string root_transaction_id { get; set; }
}

public class Result 
{
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string bsp { get; set; }
    public string dpid { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class SearchParameters
{
}
```

Finally, I use these code to get Json data:

```
string result = "Above json";
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Address add = json.Deserialize<Address>(result);
```

I see that, `add.status`, `add.search_date`... etc have values, but `add.results` is null.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The field name and property name do not match. `result` versus `results`.

Comment: I think the issue is using `@type` as illegal identifier. Try using `[DataMember(Name = "@type")]` before `public string @type { get; set; }`. Add a [DataContract] before `public class Address`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is using `@type` as illegal identifier. Try using `[DataMember(Name = "@type")]` before `public string @type { get; set; }`. Add a `[DataContract]` before `public class Address`.

Hence, your final code will be,

```
[DataContract]
public class Result 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@type")] 
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string bsp { get; set; }
    public string dpid { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string suburb { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}
```